# Como remover o primeiro item de um array sem for ou foreach

Tags: c#, .net, array

Como remover o primeiro item de um array sem for ou foreach.

Tentei assim, mas diz que não existe o método remove e nem removeAt.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

var removeu = Array.Remove(arr,0);//Agora percebi que isso é javascript, rs
```

Isso dá erro. Como eu faço? Passei isso para uma lista, mas deu erro também.

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>(arr);
```

`lista.Remove(0);` // O zero aqui não o primeiro índice.

Como eu faço agora?

Comment: tenta usar removeAt

Comment: lista.RemoveAt(0);

Comment: O problema do RemoveAt é que ele é void e não posso atribuir o valor removido assim: var primeiro = lista.RemoveAt(0); Isso dá erro.

Comment: Se você quer remover o elemento, é só isto mesmo, se quer atribuir o elemento antes de remover, apenas o faça antes de remover

Comment: @pnet resolveu o problema?

Comment: Resolveu, não da forma proposta que eu queria mas resolve, ambas as respostas resolvem. Já sei, falta fechar o post. Vou fechar sim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o seguinte código:

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
arr.RemoveAt(0);
```

Fonte: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fd84dc41-d6af-4e00-801a-b6e438de51c9/how-to-remove-the-first-element-in-a-string-array

Caso queira recuperá-lo antes, use:

```
var primeiro = arr.First();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387396/get-the-first-and-last-item-of-an-array-of-strings

Comment: Continua dando erro: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: Eu preciso atribuir o valor que está sendo removido a uma variável.

Comment: use list<int> e veja se funciona

Comment: Nota: para usar o `arr.First()`, deve-se importar o namespace `System.Linq` no arquivo.

Answer (score 5):

De acordo com o comentário o que você quer fazer é isto:

```
var primeiro = arr.RemoveAt(0);
```

Só que um *array* não possui o método `RemoveAt()` então você tem que criar um método de extensão como este [retirado do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457501/221800):

```
public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] source, int index) {
    T[] dest = new T[source.Length - 1];
    if(index > 0)
        Array.Copy(source, 0, dest, 0, index); 
    if(index < source.Length - 1)
        Array.Copy(source, index + 1, dest, index, source.Length - index - 1);
    return dest;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/RemoveAt.cs).

Comment: Isso pode ser, mas é um teste que eu estou fazendo e pelo proposto os aplicadores me deram exemplo de uma única vez a atribuição e a remoção. Por isso a insistência minha em tentar em uma única vez.

Comment: Começa que se é o que você precisa, precisa explicar melhor na pergunta. Eu não vejo outra forma de fazer isso de forma simples. Isto está fazendo em uma única vez.

Comment: esse post é parte de outro que eu fiz, por isso a parte de como fazer de uma única vez, mas está ok, vejo que não há outra forma. O outro post é esse: como implementar uma função para retornar a soma dos quadrados da forma proposta

Answer (score 1):

Se você sempre vai adicionar elementos no final e remover do inicio, você pode utilizar a classe `Queue`, que trata de fila (first in first out), ou seja, sempre quando for remover vai ser do inicio, segue um exemplo:

```
        Queue<int> fila= new Queue<int>();
        fila.Enqueue(1); //adiciona valor 1
        fila.Enqueue(2); //adiciona valor 2
        fila.Enqueue(3); //adiciona valor 3
        fila.Enqueue(4); //adiciona valor 4
        fila.Enqueue(5); //adiciona valor 5

        fila.Dequeue();//remove o primeiro elemento, neste caso o 1
```

Se este for o seu caso, a melhor estrutura de dados a se utilizar é esta.